# Silverlight Storyboard starts very slow

Tags: silverlight, performance, animation, storyboard

I need help, I have an application in Silverlight. The first page has many controls such as "Buttons, Calendars & Images" and it makes my storyboard start very slowly.

When you click an event to run the storyboard that starts very slow. I imagine this is due the large number of controls I have on my site.

How can I make my storyboard not start so slow?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an extra delay in the storyboard system firing up the first time. This is made worse of the page loading has a large number of controls.

If you make sure your animation contains some padding at the start, before anything changes, it may help reduce the visible jarring.

*If you have a specific example you care to share (Xaml etc) I would be happy to try some options on it.*